# How can i get google search query list based on location?

Tags: google, google-search, keywords, google-keyword-tool

I am looking to get queries searched on google from a particular location is it possible to access those search queries, and what are the searches happening in an area

Comment: You simple add the location on the end of the search `plumber london`, `plumber bournemouth`, `plumber poole`, this triggers Google local search and you can get more insight what users type using Adwords keyword tool.

Comment: @SimonHayter : Thank you for your reply, Actually what I am expecting is not search result, I need to get what are the searches happening in the particular location

For example, if I select the area as Delhi need to get a list of the popular search query in that area. Like that a list that contains all the search queries and volume

Answer (score 4):

Google will not reveal that information. They do show what are the most searched keywords by region in certain categories on their [Google Trends](https://trends.google.com) tools.

The *Top Charts* lets you select a country and category to see what are the top trends. For example, in Canada for 2016, the top 3 searches were: Donald Trump, Pokemon Go, Toronto Raptors. It will [show up to 10](https://trends.google.com/trends/topcharts#vm=trendingchart&cid=6dda8814-b324-47a6-a29d-d5084b24f9e2&geo=CA&date=2016&cat=) but you will not get more nor more detailed queries. So while it says *Pokemon Go*, you will not know if people searched *How to play...* or *Where to find...*.

The other way you can get more information on searches is with an AdWords account. In this case you can use the Keyword Tool there to see how many relevant searches in a particular region for your selected keywords but it will not give you the keywords. You have to input some relevant to what you are trying to do.